# Express.js cache request results with dynamic data

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, caching

Is it possible to handle cache for dynamic data? I know we can set cache in express using the following:

```
res.header('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=31557600')
```

But is it possible to set the cache the first a user access a route. For example `/latest-articles` displays the latest articles and this data is cached. So whenever a new user comes in they get the cached data within a few ms. But if someone adds a new article the cache is reset so when a user goes to `/latest-articles` or even refreshes the page they get the newly cached data.

I am guessing for this 'Server-Side' caching would be the right option. does anyone know how this can be implemented within Express.js/Node.js?

Comment: Server-side caching is all up to your server-side code. This has nothing to do with the headers.

Answer (score 0):

I think this what you're looking for: https://www.npmjs.com/package/apicache